# Rock Paper Scissors help (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Currently working on TOP rock paper scissors game and I'm having some trouble. The function playRound is showing up as undefined in the console. I'm not sure why as all my other function are working. Maybe i did something wrong in the other functions but I'm not sure. I feel like I'm so close yet so far from this thing working. Maybe it's just common beginner mistakes not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function computerPlay() {
    var pickRandom = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
    var randomMove = pickRandom[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

    if (randomMove == "Rock") {
        randomMove.value = 0;
    } else if (randomMove == "Paper") {
        randomMove.value = 1;
    } else if (randomMove == "Scissors") {
        randomMove.value = 2;
    }
    return randomMove;
}

console.log(computerPlay());


var playerSelection = prompt("pick rock paper or scissors");

function userPlay() {

    if (playerSelection == "rock") {
        playerSelection.value = 0;
    } else if (playerSelection == "paper") {
        playerSelection.value = 1;
    } else if (playerSelection == "scissors") {
        playerSelection.value = 2;
    }
    return playerSelection;
}

console.log(userPlay());

function playRound(playerPick, computerSelection) {
    if (playerPick == 0 && computerSelection == 2) {
        alert("you win!!!");
    } else if (playerPick == 0 && computerSelection == 1) {
        alert("you lose hahahahaha!!!");
    } else if (playerPick == computerSelection) {
        alert("its a tie");
    }

}

const playerPick = userPlay();
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
console.log(playRound(playerPick, computerSelection));
```

Comment: *"The function playRound is showing up as undefined in the console."* - Can you clarify what you mean by that?  The code shown appears to be trying to log the **result** of that function to the console, but that function doesn't return anything.  What specifically is the issue you're observing and how specifically does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: `playRound` doesn't return anything, that's why the result is `undefined`. Why do you run it inside `console.log`?

Comment: Also, you're assigning to properties on string primitives. That doesn't do anything useful (it doesn't, for instance, create a property on the string primitive; as soon as the assignment statement ends, it's as though it hadn't happened -- for reasons that would just be hard to understand for a beginner). Then later, you're comparing the strings with the numbers you assigned to those `value` properties (which wouldn't work even if creating the property had worked). There's no need for the numbers at all, just compare with string values.

Comment: Can you put it in a code snippet? The problem is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run it in console.log, as it doesn't have a `return` keyword, so it will return `undefined`. Just run it normally and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. I cleaned it up a bit, added a function that maps variants of human input to a normalized value, and replaced the (incomplete) conditions in `playRound` with an object that captures all of the win conditions in an object (see `beats`)...

```js
function normalizePlay(play) {
  const variants = { r: 'rock', rock: 'rock', p: 'paper', paper: 'paper', s: 'scissors', scissors: 'scissors' };
  return variants [play.toLowerCase()];
}

function computerPlay() {
    var pickRandom = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    return pickRandom[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
}

function playRound(human, computer) {
   const beats = { rock: 'scissors', scissors: 'paper', paper: 'rock' }
    let result;
    if (human === computer) {
      result = 'tie';
    } 
    else if (beats[human] === computer) {
      result = 'you win';
    }
    else result = 'computer wins';
    console.log(`you picked ${human}, computer picked ${computer}... ${result}`)
}

const human = normalizePlay(prompt("pick rock paper or scissors (or r, p, s)"));
const computer = computerPlay();
playRound(human, computer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function computerPlay() {
  var pickRandom = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
  var randomMove = pickRandom[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

  if (randomMove == "Rock") {
    return 0;
  } else if (randomMove == "Paper") {
    return 1;
  } else if (randomMove == "Scissors") {
    return 2;
  }
}



var playerSelection = prompt("pick Rock, Paper or Scissors");

function userPlay() {

  if (playerSelection == "Rock") {
    return 0;
  } else if (playerSelection == "Paper") {
    return 1;
  } else if (playerSelection == "Scissors") {
    return 2;
  }
}


function playRound(playerPick, computerSelection) {
  console.log("player", playerPick)
  console.log("computerSelection", computerSelection)
  if (playerPick == 0 && computerSelection == 2) {
    console.log("you win!!!");
  } else if (playerPick == 0 && computerSelection == 1) {
    console.log("you lose hahahahaha!!!");
  } else if (playerPick == computerSelection) {
    console.log("its a tie");
  }
}

const playerPick = userPlay();
const computerSelection = computerPlay();
playRound(playerPick, computerSelection);
```

You you just needed to return the numbers from computerPlay and userPlay. Also, be careful with case sensitivity when using the prompt.